# How to get Kit Kat style status bar on Lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, notification-bar

On my Nexus 5 I have Cyanogenmod 12 installed which is based on Lollipop. I don't like many of Android L features (OK, I know I can downgrade but not now) and I want to get back some of KK features back. Specially I want to have Kit Kat status bar and its tiled drop down menu. Is it possible?

P.S. I tried customizations but with android L I have to always touch and swipe multiple times to have the menu collapsed or expanded. I know if one swipes outside the dropdown area the menu will swipe directly up or down but it is still far from Kit Kat menu for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and I tried this : https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-get-ticker-text-notifications-on-lollipop
hope that help for status bar